# Claim: Let $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Then $f$ is an injection

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Show that the function is an injection by finding a left-inverse of the function, or explain why you can't find such a function given $f$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

**My Attempt**

Proof. To prove that $f$ is injective, we need only to show that there exists a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R^+}$ we have $(g \circ f)(x)=x$.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $g(x)=x^2$.

- Totality: Because every element of the domain, $\mathbb{R}$, is assigned to something; that is, the square of any real number is defined, it follows that the totality condition is satisfied.
- Existence: Every assignment is not a well-defined existing element of $\mathbb{R^+}$. Counterexample: Let $x=0 \in\mathbb{R}$, but $g(0) = 0 \notin \mathbb{R^+}$
- Uniqueness: As every element of the domain is assigned to only one element of the codomain $\Rightarrow$ existence is satisfied.

As $g$ does not satisfy the condition $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists! y \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $g(x)=y$ $\Rightarrow$ $g$ is not a well-defined left-inverse of $f$.

However, if $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then $f$ is an injection whereby $g: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ defined by $g(x)=x^2$ is its left-inverse; that is, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $g(f(x)) = x$.

Comment: What is your question exactly? To show that $f$ is injective, it is enough to show that $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$.

Comment: Show that the function is an injection by finding a left-inverse of the function, or explain why you can't find such a function.

Comment: If $f$ is injection on $ \mathbb{R^+} \to  \mathbb{R^+} $, then adding points to image will change it?

Comment: Yes. My argument is that given how f is defined, it can't have a left-inverse. And so if f was defined differently, then it would have a left-inverse. But I guess that's not what the problem is asking, so I can omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only shown that $\textbf{one particular}$ function $g$ does not match the property. To show that $f$ is not injective, you must show that there $\textbf{cannot exists any}$ such $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+ $. There might be (and there are) other functions $g$ that act as a left-inverse.

Just because YOU don't speak French, it does not mean no one else can speak it either.

Consider $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ by
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 &\text{ if } x\neq 0 \\ 42 &\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$$
Then for all $x\in \mathbb R^+$ you have $f(x) \in \mathbb R^+$ so $f(x) \neq 0$ therefore $$(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$$
and therefore $f$ is injective.

Comment: Excuse my assumption if you do actually speak French :P Point's been made either way.

Comment: Typo in line 3: should be “to show that f is not injective..”

Comment: @Karam edited, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP's analysis has received a response, it is open season to use an alternative method to demonstrate that $f:\Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}^+ ~: ~f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is injective.

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} > 0 ~$ for all $x > 0.$

Therefore, $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.  Therefore, if $x < y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ is an injection.

Comment: Or just observe $x-y = (\sqrt x)^2-(\sqrt y)^2 = (\sqrt x - \sqrt y)(\sqrt x + \sqrt y)$ thus as $\sqrt x + \sqrt y \geq 0$ we have $x-y < 0$ iff. $\sqrt x -\sqrt y > 0$. Thus  $x<y \implies f(x)  = \sqrt x < \sqrt y =f(y)$